# transitioned book isn't working in fire fox and micro edge-why and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Transitions and transforms dont seem to be working properly for me in firefox, I added the -moz- prefix to everything, but its seems to have had zero effect on making it more functional. I have a book that opens when hovered over,but in fire fox the book doesnt open all the way and closes before the mouse moves off of it. The transitions and transforms not used on the book seem to be working, its seems the ones in the book are the issue. As for microsoft edge it's working but the background-image,before abd after pesudo elements and a div I have on it, arent showing up. the book cover is just blank on microsoft edge. Does anyone with more experience understand the issue here? it works fine in chrome but not in firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/ma2u65o0/

```
 //book css snippet
.book-front{
        position: relative;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: left;
        -moz-transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
        perspective: 400px;
        perspective-origin: -200px;
         }
.front-of-book-front{
        background-image: url("images/mainCover.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 47%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `backface-visibility:hidden` to your `.front-of-book-front` makes it transparent after open-and-close action.

Also I'd recommend you using 3d transforms for hardware acceleration.

The updated css:

```
.front-of-book-front,
.back-of-book-front,
.book-front,
.book-back,
.book{
    width: 100px;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
}
.book{
     margin: 52px auto;
     transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
.book-front{
        position: relative;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        perspective: 400px;
        perspective-origin: -200px;
         }
.front-of-book-front{
    background-image: url("images/mainCover.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 47%;
        }
.front-of-book-front:before{
    content: "Seraph Chronicles: Evangelion";
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-size: .5em;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 119px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate3d(8px,93px,0) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.front-of-book-front:after{
    content: "";
    width: 75px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(0px,19px,0);
  }
 .bar{
    width: 80px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    font-size: .3em;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    transform: rotateZ(90deg) translate3d(36px,-45px,0);
     }

.bar p{
    padding: 2px 3px 0 0 ;
    display: block;
}
.back-of-book-front{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(240,234,214);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.book:hover .book-front {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        }
.book:hover{
    transform: rotateZ(10deg);
            }

.book-back{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color: rgb(240,234,214);
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: justify;
}

.book-back p{
        font-size: .3rem;
        margin: 2.9em 1.9em;
}

@media screen and (min-wdith:400px){

   .front-of-book-front,
    .back-of-book-front,
    .book-front,
    .book-back,
    .book{
        width: 113px;
        height: 180px;
        }

    .front-of-book-front:before{
        width: 133px;
        height: 17px;
        transform: translate3d(8px,105px,0) rotateZ(90deg);
    }

    .front-of-book-front:after{
        width: 83px;
        height: 14px;
        transform: translate3d(0,21px,0);
    }
    .bar{
        width: 95px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        font-size: .3em;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        transform: rotateZ(90deg) translate3d(42px,-45px,0);
         }
    .book-back p{
        font-size: .4rem;
        margin: 2.9em 1.9em;
    }
    .book-side{
        width: 176px;
        height: 10px;
        top:-3px;
        }
}

@media screen and (min-width:860px){
  .front-of-book-front,
    .back-of-book-front,
    .book-front,
    .book-back,
    .book{
        width: 200px;
        height: 320px;
        }
    .front-of-book-front{
        perspective: 200px;
    }
    .front-of-book-front:before{
        width: 234px;
        height: 37px;
        transform: translate3d(11px,185px,0) rotateZ(90deg);
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 37px;
    }

    .front-of-book-front:after{
        width: 146px;
        height: 26px;
        transform: translate3d(0,32px,0);
    }
    .bar{
        width: 172px;
        height: 23px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        font-size: .3em;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        transform: rotateZ(90deg) translate3d(74px,-82px,0);
        font-size: .7em;
         }
    .bar p{
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .book-side{
        width: 312px;
        height: 10px;
        top:-1px;
        left: -5px;

        }
    .book-back p{
        font-size: .7em;
        margin: 3.3em 2.3em;
    }
```

}

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, you'll get the best answer, I just want to make sure that I fully understand, so I dont make the mistake again first. The issue was in fire fox. I had the hover css on the front of the cover and as it rotated on its axis y  axis, it stopped being under the cursors, thank you. But I'm a bit confused as to the role backface-visibility and z-index had. You said too much backface-visibility and more z-index, could you further explain the reasons why its was too much and too less of them, so I fully understand. Thanks again

Comment: Normally is there a limit to how much you should use backface-visibility: hidden? for like performance reasons?

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my answer. Obviously there is no limit for `backface-visibility:hidden`. Also I was wrong with z-indexes. My bad.

Comment: just gave you the bounty sorry, I thought it did it automatically with best answer